# How to add a second router?

Tags: networking, router, adsl

Being sick of shaky WiFi connection to our home's main router (a Sitecom, which is far away) I've got a New Belkin router to use in my room. I have a telephone plug in my room but not sure whether it is possible to  directly connect the Belkin to the plug and connect to the home's ADSL.

I am using Ubuntu, hence I cannot use the supplied Belkin installation CD, and this adds another layer of difficulty/uncertainity.

I appreciate your hints to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: Does your internet connection come in directly or are you pulling it off your ISP's modem/router/hardware?

Comment: @Shinrai, If it is ADSL, it has to go through a modem.

Comment: @MaQleod - I figured that was the case, but I ask the OP to make sure he means exactly what he's saying by 'ADSL', since I don't know his level of expertise.

Comment: If both routers support WDS, that's what you want to use. Make sure the new router's DHCP server is disabled, and don't use its WAN/Internet port.

Answer (score 1):

There is some need to disambiguate different situations.

- Your phone plug is connected in parallel to the other phone plug your current router is connected too, or you need the phone line for a phone:

  No chance to use this line. Everything you connect will disturb your primary ADSL connection.
- Your phone plug ends up unconnected or in some telephone switchboard and you don't need your phone line:

  You could use your phone line for some ADSL-like connection or use some powerline-adapter which supports phone lines. Both times expected to be more expensive than a simple powerline solution as stated before.
- You've got a dedicated phone line which is directly connected to your phone company:

  Order a seperate DSL connection. I never heard of an ADSL provider allowing you to connect using different phone lines without paying multiple times.

All in all, these solutions (apart from the first) only fit in some special cases. Typically you're left with three alternatives:

- Install an ethernet cable. Best solution if possible, no additional power consumption and no problems with weak signal.
- Use some wireless extender too strengthen your wireless signal.
- Buy a powerline adaptor. Will probably work within the same flat, sometimes also the whole house. Needs some extra power, but usually is more stable than wireless networks.

Comment: Ranon, as far as I can see, my room's phone plug is a normal plug taht you can see in every residence roome. Does this mean that it is a parallel plug, and hence no chance of getting connected through the second router? Thanks

Comment: Where does it end (in some phone switchboard?)? Are you able to do phone calls with that plug? Do you need special phones?